# Get the string with the highest value in java (strings have the same 'base' name but different suffixes)

Tags: java, string, comparison

I have a list with some strings in it:

```
GS_456.java
GS_456_V1.java
GS_456_V2.java
GS_460.java
GS_460_V1.java
```

And it goes on. I want a list with the strings with the highest value:

```
GS_456_V2.java
GS_460_V1.java
.
.
.
```

I'm only thinking of using lots of for statements...but isn't there a more pratical way? I'd like to avoid using too many for statements...since i'm using them a lot when i execute some queries...

EDIT: The strings with the V1, V2,.... are the names of recent classes created. When someone creates a new version of GS_456 for example, they'll do it and add its version at the end of the name.

So, GS_456_V2 is the most recent version of the GS_456 java class. And it goes on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by highest value ? what is your comparison criteria ? how GS_456_V2 > GS_460_V1 ?

Comment: Are you interested in just lexicographic order? Or would you potentially have "GS_1000" which should be higher than "GS_460"?

Comment: You want the highest in each group, where a group is defined by a common GS_nnn prefix? How do you think you could tell a computer what to do, if you cannot even make it clear to humans?

Comment: @Ingo
That's what i want...Sorry for the bad explanation...

Comment: Then you just sort in reverse, then go through the list and keep only the first entry of several that have the same prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to process the file names in two steps.

Step 1: split the list into sublists, with one sublist per file name (ignoring suffix).
Here is an example that splits the list into a Map:

```
 private static Map> nameMap = new HashMap>();

    private static void splitEmUp(final List names)
    {
        for (String current : names)
        {
            List listaly;
            String[] splitaly = current.split("_|\\.");

            listaly = nameMap.get(splitaly[1]);
            if (listaly == null)
            {
                listaly = new LinkedList();
                nameMap.put(splitaly[1], listaly);
            }

            listaly.add(current);
        }
```

Step 2: find the highest prefix for each name.  Here is an example:

```
 private static List findEmAll()
    {
        List returnValue = new LinkedList();

        Set keySet = nameMap.keySet();
        for (String key : keySet)
        {
            List listaly = nameMap.get(key);
            String highValue = null;

            if (listaly.size() == 1)
            {
                highValue = listaly.get(0);
            }
            else
            {
                int highVersion = 0;

                for (String name : listaly)
                {
                    String[] versions = name.split("_V|\\.");

                    if (versions.length == 3)
                    {
                        int versionNumber = Integer.parseInt(versions[1]);
                        if (versionNumber > highVersion)
                        {
                            highValue = name;
                            highVersion = versionNumber;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            returnValue.add(highValue);
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't want simply the lexicographic order (the solution would be obvious).

First, remove the ".java" part and split your string on the character "_".

```
int dotIndex = string.indexOf(".");
String []parts = split.substring(0, dotIndex).split("_");
```

You are interested in parts[1] and parts[2]. The first is easy, it's just a number.

```
int fileNumber = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
```

The second one is always of the form "VX" with X being a number. But this part may not exist (if it's the base version of the file). In which case we can say that version is 0.

```
int versionNumber = parts.length < 2 ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(parts[2].substring(1));
```

Now you can compare based on these two numbers.

To make things simple, build a class FileIdentifier based on this:

```
class FileIdentifier {
     int fileNumber;
     int versionNumber;
}
```

Then a function that create a FileIdentifier from a file name, with logic based on what I explained earlier.

```
FileIdentifier getFileIdentifierFromFileName(String filename){ /* .... */ }
```

Then you make a comparator on String, in which you get the FileIdentifier for the two strings and compare upon FileIdentifier members.

Then, to get the string with "the highest value", you simply put all your strings in a list, and use `Collections.sort`, providing the comparator.